# How to edit a property of another class and return it to another class?

Tags: php

So my problem is : I'm creating a management system with php, html5, css etc(school project).

When a user logs in I save its data in a class. The whole purpose of saving them is to later on use them when a purchase is done, so I can save the product ID and the user ID. But whenever I do the query to the DB I get an Undefined variable error.

This is my class and its methods in it. One is used to save data and one to return them.

```
class profile_attributes{
    public $u_data;
    function attributes($u_data){
        $this->u_data=$u_data;
    }
    function attr_get(){
        return  $u_data;
    }
}
```

How I initially send arguments

```
 $u_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $save_info = new profile_attributes()->attributes($u_data);
```

How I try to get them

```
$profile = new profile_attributes();
$loged_user = $profile->attr_get();

$user_id = $loged_user['id'];
```

Comment: what does a var_dump of $loged_user['id'] return?

Comment: Where is the code that calls the `attributes` method?

Comment: Aren't you looking for session variables?

Comment: `attr_get` should return `$this->udata`. But as trincot wrote, you also need to make sure you actually set the property.

Comment: You said, "I save its data in a class. The whole purpose of saving them is to later on use them when a purchase is done".  Even after you correctly implement your getters and setters, a class is not persistent.  If you're wanting to use the information in subsequent page loads, you must use a database, session variable, or other persistent storage.

Comment: @Juakali92 I'm passing an associative array...

Comment: @trincot I just edit my post ...

Comment: @TimMorton I want to exclude an extra connection to DB, as for session I'm using only two types of them and I don't see how a session can help me

Comment: I don't understand either of your comments.  If you want to use the data "later", you will have to persist it using a database or with a session variable, because each session (page view) is starting over from scratch.  Typically the session id identifies who is making the request, and then you grab persisted data from the database.

Comment: Now, ignoring the word "later", perhaps you are looking at how to send data from one object to another (in the same session).  If that's the case, what you're needing is called dependency injection.  Basically, it's just one object accepting another object as a property.  Then, the receiving object can access all methods and properties of the received object.

Comment: @TimMorton I think session doesn't play any role here, since all the time he is opened right after I send arguments to the first method of "profile_attributes", the user can browse the page meanwhile and do anything , but when is purchasing sth I want to use this data that i previously saved in "profile_attributes" class. Both instanced are created in separate php  files.

Comment: OK, one other clarification needed:  are you writing this as a web application, or as a stand-alone GUI using PHP-GTK that never ends (ie, loops while waiting for commands)?  Because to have a stand-alone gui is pretty rare.  If you're using the web in *any* way, you have to realize that the application is stateless.  As soon as the app finishes a request, it's done, kapoot.  If you want information from one page to the next, you *must* use some sort of session to track the user and a database (be it on the server or on browser's local storage) to persist the data.

Comment: @TimMorton It is a web-application. So even though I send argument to the class, nothing is saved to the memory?

Comment: Nothing is saved to memory.  The class only holds a value for the duration of the script's running.

Comment: @TimMorton Thank you, it's what I've been in doubt the whole time, feels like chasing ghosts the whole time.... Does using a superglobal($GLOBALS) would give solution to my problem ?

Comment: Nope.  Each call to a script starts it with a fresh state.  So to persist data, you have to use a session variable to uniquely identify the user, and then use that id to get info from persistent storage (database).  You *could* also store serialized data in a session variable.  So what you need to research is the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: @TimMorton Thank you for answer. I did researched and you are right. Sorry for my ignorance in this field but im relatively new to php, and as I mention this is my school project. Thank you once again.

Comment: glad to help.  Looks like they tossed you in the deep end without teaching some of the basics.  Once you get it, though, it's fun.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're ever defining $u_data. All you're doing is creating a new instance of profile_attributes and then trying to pull the undefined $u_data.

Answer (score 0):

$u_data is not defined, you must precede with $this

```
class profile_attributes{
    public $u_data;
    function attributes($u_data){
        $this->u_data=$u_data;
    }
    function attr_get(){
        return  $this->u_data;
    }
}
```

You were creating an instance to set the attributes and another to access them, use just one for both:

```
// Use the same instance to set and get atributes
$profile = new profile_attributes();
$u_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$save_info = $profile->attributes($u_data);

$loged_user = $profile->attr_get();
$user_id = $loged_user['id'];
```

Comment: This still doesn't looks to be helping me... :/

Comment: Maybe you just need to set attributes before access them. I've editted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two separate *instances* of your `profile_attributes` class. An instance's properties and data are specific to itself, and do not get shared if you create a second instance using the `new class` syntax.

Here's an example of what you're doing. Notice that the data inside the instances are not the same:

```
class Foo
{
    public $data;
}

$instance1 = new Foo();
$instance1->data = array[1, 2, 3];

$instance2 = new Foo();

var_dump($instance1, $instance2);
```

You need to share the first instance you create and save the database result to the place where you want to retrieve those attributes.

Comment: Since my attribute is in my class scope and public, doesn't this make it common for both of my methods that are in the class ??

Comment: Think of it like this: Your class definition is a set of instructions to build a cabinet. Each time you do `new Cabinet()`, you build a brand new cabinet. In your case, you now have two Cabinets. If you were to put books (data) in one cabinet, they would not magically become accessible in the other cabinet as well.

Comment: `class Foo {}` just defines a _blueprint_ of an object's structure. Each _instance_ of that class is a separate object, each with its own state, data, etc., but all with the same _structure_ as defined by the blueprint.

Comment: My instances are in separate php files, the first one who deliver information is when a user is logging in and the other when he is doing an purchase.

Comment: Then you need to do one of two things: A) persist data between PHP page requests via _sessions_, or B) retrieve the data you need in the same page that places the order. Both are outside the scope of the question you asked.

Comment: If I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking for it, anyway thank you for your dedication.